# how to start compass using a batch file

Tags: batch-file

Hello can anyone tell me how I can start compass using a batch file?

```
cmd.exe /K "cd C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\ && C:"
compass watch "e:/project/html/"
```

But after it opens the correct location it does not start the line *compass watch*

Comment: Surely if you are writing a batch file, you do not need to call `cmd.exe`?  just execute the `cd` command on its own.

Comment: Your Problem ist the /K switch, which tells cmd.exe not to stop after execution, so your second line is never reached.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a batch file (*path\batchfile.bat*) :

```
c:
cd C:\Ruby200-x64\bin\
compass watch "e:/project/html/"
```

Then execute :
`cmd.exe /c "path\batchfile.bat"`

Answer (score 3):

Simple way which worked for me; have the batch file in the project folder with line:

```
compass watch
```

No need for changing paths if you move the project folder for example. For me it's convenient to just open the project folder and double click the file to start working.

Comment: Just make sure that your batch file isn't named "compass.bat", otherwise it will load itself in an endless loop.